# Definition of a category as a monoid

Tags: category-theory

This is my first time writing here. If you want me to write my questions in another way, please let me know because I have no experience in doing that at all.

I am using the book of MacLane introducing the concept of categories.

Let $O$ be a set of objects and $A$ a set of arrows.

A category can be seen as a monoid $(A, \circ)$ by using the following “product over the set O” which is the set of all composable pairs $$A \times_O A = \{\langle f,g \rangle : f,g \in A \text{ with } dom(g) = cod(f) \}.$$

As set we do have the set of arrows. As inner binary operation we do have the composition $\circ$. Associativity is given by the common definition of a category (MacLane).

I would like to show properly the condition of the existence of the neutral element. We know that there exists for each arrow $f: a \to b$ the identity arrows $id_a$ and $id_b$ so that $$f \circ id_a = id_b \circ f = f.$$ But it should be rewritten in a way so that it makes sense with the definition of a neutral element and we can write a real triple $(A,\circ, e)$.

Could you give me some hints? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In one line, what MacLane is saying is that (small) categories are monads in the bicategory of spans of sets.

More precisely: monoids are a notion that makes sense in any monoidal category. Fix the set $O$ and consider the category $\mathbf G_O$ whose objects are the triples $(A,s,t)$ with $s,t$ maps $A \to O$ and whose mrophisms $(A,s,t) \to (A',s',t')$ are the map $F:A \to A'$ such that $s=s'F$ and $t=t'F$. Then there is a monoidal product on $\mathbf G_O$ defined as:
$$ (A,s,t) \otimes (A',s',t') := (\{(f,f') \in  A\times A' : t(f) = s'(f')\}, (f,f')\mapsto s(f), (f,f') \mapsto t'(f')) $$ 
The unit for this monoidal product is $(O,\mathrm{id}_O,\mathrm{id}_O)$. The claim is that a monoid in this monoidal category $\mathbf G_O$ is precisely a (samll) category with set of objects $O$. In particular, the unit of such a monoid is expressed as a map $e : (O,\mathrm{id}_O,\mathrm{id}_O) \to (A,s,t)$ in $\mathbf G_O$, meaning a map $e:O \to A$ such that $s=se$ and $t=te$.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting question, I never realised we could see a category in this way!

Before I answer your question, let me first point out where in MacLane's *Categories for the Working Mathematician* the relevant definitions can be found (in case anyone else is interested). Page 10 defines the sets $O$, $A$ and the product $A \times_O A$, together with how these sets with the necessary operations form a category. Earlier, in the introduction, on page 2 it is explained what a monoid is in terms of diagrams (with their usual meaning, with respect to the cartesian product $\times$). Then on page 4 it is explained how we can replace the usual cartesian product $\times$ by a similar binary operation $\square$.

**The question is then**: given a category with $A$ and $O$ as its set of arrows and objects respectively, in the case where this operation $\square$ is given by $\times_O$, what is the neutral element for the monoid $(A, \circ)$?

For any such operation $\square$, the neutral element will be given by an arrow $1 \to A$, where $1$ is the unit of the operation $A \square A$. That is, for all objects $X$, we must have isomorphisms
$$
1 \square X \cong X \cong X \square 1.
$$
Note that if $\square$ is the cartesian product $\times$, then 1 is just a singleton and an arrow $1 \to A$ just amounts to an element of $A$. So this is why we usually think of it as just an element. For other operations than the cartesian product, the unit may be something more complex than just a singleton and we get a 'neutral element' that is no longer just an element.

One of these more complex cases is where $\square$ is $\times_O$. First let us determine the unit. I will denote the unit of this operation by $I$ to avoid confusion in notation. So we want some set $I$ such that for all $B \subseteq A$ ($\times_O$ is only defined on subsets of $A$), there are isomorphisms:
$$
I \times_O B \cong B \cong B \times_O I.
$$
It turns out that taking
$$
I = \{ id_a : a \in O \}
$$
will do the job (check this!).

Now the 'neutral element' (which is no longer just one element) will be given by an arrow $I \to A$. There is only one, very natural, choice here and that is the inclusion. You should check that this indeed makes the entire construction into a monoid. So the 'neutral element' is now actually a subset of $A$.

Comment: It seems a bit strange to me to write $I$ in that way, rather than just $I=O$, although I guess it works. More importantly, $\times_O$ is not defined on subsets of $O$ (the set of arrows is rarely a subset of the set of objects!) In fact it's defined for any set equipped with two functions into $O$. The definition $A\times_O A=\{(a,a'): t(a)=s(a')\}$ works for any such $s,t:A\to O$. (In particular this is not the usual pullback of objects over or subobjects of $O$.)

Comment: Well, as you already mentioned, arrows and objects are different things. We are looking for a set of arrows here, so I'd say $I=O$ is the strange one. You can indeed define a similar operation $\times_O$ for any set with two functions into $O$. Although the notation does not show it, $\times_O$ depends on what these functions precisely are. For subobjects $B, C$ of $A$ (indeed, not $O$) $B \times_O C$ is in fact their pullback (in the category of sets) when composing with $dom$ and $cod$.